# Scalable Featured Images - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Bootstrap3 to create a Wordpress theme, and I am using the responsive columns like so:

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></p>
                    <p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary">Take a look</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I've noticed though is that the featured images are not scalable.  They have set sizes, but you can't define them so that the width is 100% of, in my example, the class panel-body.

I'd like to do this as when the screen size changes, so do the size of the columns, and I'd like the image to scale with them.

Does anyone know a way of doing this,  I seem to have become a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to make image scalable:

```
<?php 
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive img-circle')); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Why to add `img-circle`?

Comment: you can use any bootstrap class for image  ..its up to you..if you don't want to use circle image in column you can drop it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add class `.img-responsive` to make images responsive with bootstrap 3.

For adding the class `.img-responsive` to your wordpress images you can add the below function in your `functions.php` file.

```
<?php 
//----------------------------------------------------------/
//  responsive images [ 1) add img-responsive class 2) remove dimensions ]
//----------------------------------------------------------/

function bootstrap_responsive_images( $html ){
  $classes = 'img-responsive'; // separated by spaces, e.g. 'img image-link'

  // check if there are already classes assigned to the anchor
  if ( preg_match('/<img.*? class="/', $html) ) {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<img.*? class=".*?)(".*?\/>)/', '$1 ' . $classes . ' $2', $html);
  } else {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<img.*?)(\/>)/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" $2', $html);
  }
  // remove dimensions from images,, does not need it!
  $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
  return $html;
}
add_filter( 'the_content','bootstrap_responsive_images',10 );
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'bootstrap_responsive_images', 10 );
```

Hope it helps you.